# How to send videos as attachment in chat message Quickblox Android App?

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

I have integrated Quickblox Android SDK into my app for chat module.

Images as an attachment is possible. But I can't find any working solution to make a video attachment file under the same request.

I have confirmed by reading a document from Quickblox which says - Video attachment possible under Quickblox chat SDK.

Do anyone has any working solution to make video file attachment with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a pass file it doesn't matter its image or  video, like you're passing image file.
further process is same

Comment: @Surabhi Can u show your code here for uploading image and video ?